# Supported web.config settings in Mono ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mono

How can I find out which web.config settings are supported by Mono's implementation of ASP.NET?

Specifically I'm having trouble getting the <staticContent> settings to work, and wondering if this simply isn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

I ran `grep staticContent -Ri .` over the newest mono source code and it could not find a thing. I conclude that it is not supported by mono itself.

Anyway, `staticContent` belongs to the `system.webServer` namespace, so it is a matter of the webserver, not the mono runtime. [Microsoft lists](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent) `staticContent` as supported since IIS 7.0.

**EDIT**: Since you are using `Mono.WebServer.FastCgi`, there is a file which contains all supported options: [ConfigurationManager.xml](https://github.com/mono/xsp/blob/master/src/Mono.WebServer.FastCgi/ConfigurationManager.xml). Note that these are usually passed to the server on the command line.

But I really think it only feels responsible for mono server scripts ("CGI"), not for static content, which should be handled by the webserver.

Comment: Right, but somewhere in the pipeline the mono fast-cgi server does serve up static files - so I was hoping it would honour these settings.  (I'm running mono behind lighttpd which is configured to pass all requests to the mono fast cgi server).

Comment: You didn't mention which server you used

Comment: I just also greped over the xsp source and I couldn't find the string `staticContent`. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Meinersbur.  ConfigurationManager.xml looks like settings for the fcgi server, not the application.  The reason I'm serving all files through the fcgi server is because of the comments about security here: http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Lighttpd.  That said though these are simple scripts/css/images that don't really need security anyway, so I think I'll get lighty to serve them directly.  Thanks.